# Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/nodemon' while using docker-compose

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, nodemon

I am trying to create a docker-compose.yml to be able to run my crud-admin panel using both my backend and frontend API together in the same network with docker. This is the first time i am using an "docker-compose" file to deploy with docker. Usually i deploy each API itself using a normal Dockerfile.

when running the command : `docker-compose up --build` i get the error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/nodemon'
```

I have:

- tried with sudo as well even though my user is added to docker group
- my user has sudo privileges
- I have tried an update

before posting my Dockerfile and docker compose, here is my folder structure:

```
the-admin-panel
│
├──frontend(reactjs/nextjs)
│  ├─ .next
│  ├─ components
│  ├─ content
│  ├─ helper
│  ├─ pages
│  ├─ public
│  ├─ services
│  ├─ static
│  ├─ next.config
│  ├─ next-env.d
│  ├─ package.json
│  ├─ package-lock.json
│  ├─ tsconfig.json
│  ├─ Dockerfile
│  ├─ .dockerignore
│  
│
├──backend(nodejs)
│  ├─ api
│  ├─ startup
│  ├─ middleware
│  ├─ models
│  ├─ server.js
│  ├─ package.json
│  ├─ package-lock.json
│  ├─ .env
│  ├─ Dockerfile
│  ├─ .dockerignore
│  
├──docker-compose.yml
```

Currently, the frontend is not finished yet, so for now im only trying to deploy the backend, so im focusing on this part for now.

Here is the Dockerfile for my backend:

```
FROM node:13-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000
CMD [ "nodemon", "server.js"]
```

As you can see, im trying to run it with "nodemon".

And finally, here is my docker-compose.yml file(notice that i have commented all the lines within the frontend section as the frontend api is not finished yet)

```
version: '3'
services:

#set up the frontend
  #frontend:
  #  build:
  #    context: frontend
  #    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  #  image: frontend
  #    - $PWD:/usr/src/app
  #    - /usr/src/app/node_modules
  #  restart: always
  #  ports:
  #    - "3000:3000"
  #  networks:
  #    testnetwork

#set up the backend
  backend:
    build:
      context: backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: nodejs-restapi
    #- $PWD:/usr/src/app
    #- /usr/src/app/node_modules

    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    networks:
            testnetwork:


# Set up shared network
networks:
  testnetwork:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 10.0.0.0/8
```

in case if needed, here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "..",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "..",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "tim",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "fastest-validator": "^1.10.0",
    "helmet": "^4.4.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```

Could someone help me solve this nodemon issue?

Comment: Include your package.json too

Comment: It is now included.

Comment: try running `CMD ["./node_modules/.bin/nodemon", "server.js"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is just a trial. So, without much production-grade adjustments, I would suggest you try changing your dockerfile.

```
FROM node:13-alpine

COPY . /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g nodemon

EXPOSE 5000
CMD [ "nodemon", "server.js"]
```

Comment: I tried it, error is still the same:


backend_1  | internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965
backend_1  |   throw err;
backend_1  | Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/nodemon'
backend_1  |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:962:15)
backend_1  |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:838:27)
backend_1  |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
backend_1  |     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
backend_1  |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
backend_1  |   requireStack: []

Comment: Do you get the same error when you do this: `CMD [ "node", "server.js"]`

Comment: no, when using "node" instead, it works perfectly.

Comment: Try adding this command just before the EXPOSE command  `RUN npm install -g nodemon `

Comment: This seems to be working!! 

But should this Cmd line still be like this:

CMD [ "node", "server.js"]

or should i try changing it to:

CMD [ "nodemon", "server.js"] ?

EDIT: I tested and it also worked with "nodemon" insteade of "node" inside the CMD!

Thank you!!

Comment: You can click on the "correct" mark under each answer and mark the correct one as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply suggest not using `nodemon` inside a docker image. `nodemon` is a tool for development, and I don't think there's much use for running it in production/any other environment you deploy to.

simply change the last line in your backend's `Dockerfile` to
`CMD [ "node", "server.js"]`

Comment: I was actually using the CMD like the one you suggested. But someone else told me to change "node" to "nodemon" in order to be able to use nodemon, which i probably need to use in order to be able to reload the docker container automatically when i upload new files.

Comment: What kind of files are you uploading to your container? If you're releasing a new version of your backend you should run a new container, not update the files in the current container, that's the whole point of containers. They're meant to be ephemeral. If it's anything else, I don't see why the server has to restart as a reaction to file upload. Please elaborate.

Comment: For now it is for development used by the developers. Thats why.

Comment: Why use a docker container to run a server that's being developed? Unclear to me, but I am quite sure you can do without `nodemon` in the image.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so thanks to Charlie, the solution was a small change in the Dockerfile where "RUN npm install -g nodemon" was added.

```
FROM node:13-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm install -g nodemon  #this was needed in order to make it work

EXPOSE 5000

CMD [ "nodemon", "server.js"]
```